# Magento Contact Form says successful. Suddenly it isn't.

Tags: php, forms, email, magento-1.7, contacts

About three weeks ago, my contact form on my Mage 1.7.0.0 site stopped functioning.  After submission it took you to the success page, but no email was ever recieved.

We are using GApps.  I confirmed PHP could send mail from the server, okay.  I used SMTP Pro extension, and could send a test email from within the admin.  But still no contact form functionality.

I removed all extensions.

As the form.phtml we are using is edited, i replaced it with the stock form.phtml from the Magento 1.7.0.0 Zip.  Now, on submission, am greeting with an error, 'try again later'.

Exception.log definitely shows an issue using php or smtp:

```
2014-07-02T21:07:10+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 
'No recipient forward path has been supplied' in 
/chroot/home/domain/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:309
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /chroot/home/domain/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(215): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->data('Reply-To: chris...')
#1 /chroot/home/domain/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#2 /chroot/home/domain/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#3 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php(106): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#4 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send(NULL, NULL, Array)
#5 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php(105): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('contacts_email_...', 'general', NULL, NULL, Array)
#6 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction()
#7 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#8 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /chroot/home/domain/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /chroot/home/domain/html/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

**abstract.php** line 348: $this->_sendMail();

**transport/smtp.php** line 215:  $this->_connection->data($this->header . Zend_Mime::LINEEND . $this->body);

**protocol/smtp/php** Line 209: throw new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception('No recipient forward path has been supplied');

I am not sure exactly what the change needed would be...Any assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

look on

```
$mail->addTo($mail, $name);
```

1) **trim** $mail

2) check $name - **is array or not** --- need as string